# Tailwind Putting Circle Inside Button

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do I put a circle inside the button with a text on its right side?
Right now, its overlapping the text, they should be centered (circle + text).
here's the playground [CLICK HERE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zUnYfAnyMs)

```
<button class="btn btn-change">
  <span class="w-5 h-5 bg-red-500 rounded-full absolute"></span>
  Change Color
</button>
```

Comment: You can try this https://play.tailwindcss.com/WNW7XPOEPr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-change">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
      <span class="w-5 h-5 bg-red-500 rounded-full"></span>
    Change Color
  </div> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-change">
  <div class="flex  justify-center">
    <span class="w-5 h-5 bg-red-500 rounded-full"></span>
  Change Color
  </div>
</button>
```